# Can some one please explain to me the difference between reshape and resize in a keras?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, reshape

I have been looking through the internet and i am a bit confused. It is doing the same things so why do we need a resize and a reshape and which is better ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53656223/9524424